# Not understanding collision detection code

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision-detection

I came across this topic on Stackoverflow about collision detection between a circle and a rectangle.

The original post can be found here @markE: [Detecting collision of rectangle with circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089959/detecting-collision-of-rectangle-with-circle-in-html5-canvas)

```
var circle={x:100,y:290,r:10};
var rect={x:100,y:100,w:40,h:100};

// return true if the rectangle and circle are colliding
function RectCircleColliding(circle,rect){
var distX = Math.abs(circle.x - rect.x-rect.w/2);
var distY = Math.abs(circle.y - rect.y-rect.h/2);

if (distX > (rect.w/2 + circle.r)) { return false; }
if (distY > (rect.h/2 + circle.r)) { return false; }

if (distX <= (rect.w/2)) { return true; } 
if (distY <= (rect.h/2)) { return true; }

var dx=distX-rect.w/2;
var dy=distY-rect.h/2;
    return (dx*dx+dy*dy<=(circle.r*circle.r));
}
```

Can someone please explain the last bit of code to me?

```
var dx=distX-rect.w/2;
var dy=distY-rect.h/2;
return (dx*dx+dy*dy<=(circle.r*circle.r));
```

I really don't understand the math behind it.

Maybe someone can post a photo that might help me visualize it? I have attached a photo that I drew while trying to figure it out.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: You should ask you question on the original Question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting collision of rectangle with circle in html5 canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089959/detecting-collision-of-rectangle-with-circle-in-html5-canvas)

Comment: @Jon i tried to leave a comment but it said i need 50 rep points to be able to do that

Comment: It's just pythagoras theorem, which gives the distance between two elements (the long side of a triangle). In mathematics it is even defined as the distance (although it is in terms of a metric...). Further more, it's written as dx*dx instead of dx^2 because in some languages it is faster (although in most languages it would be optimized away anyways...)

Comment: @user228395 So does it give the distance from the center of the circle to the nearest corner of the rect. Or is it just the distance from the center of the rect to the corner? Also, why did he square the radius of the circle? thank youu :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. So `dx` is just the "horizontal" distance of the rectangle edge to the circle center. The same for `dy`: it is the length from the vertical edge of the rectangle to the circle center.

Now according to Pythagoras, if you want the length to the corner of the rectangle (from the circle center), you take the square root of `dx^2` + `dy^2`.

Now you want to know if the corner "sticks"  into the circle.

For this the square root of `dx^2+dy^2` has to be smaller than (or equal to) the radius of the circle. Thus: `sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2) <= circle.r`.

Square both sides of the equation to obtain `dx^2 + dy^2 <= circle.r^2`.