# HTML5 bouncing elements

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, collision, gravity

I am looking to have a HTML5 canvas with both circle elements and square elements bouncing around the cavnas but also bouncing off each other and colliding, hopefully spinning on collision.

The closest thing I have found is this https://codepen.io/gichmbugua/pen/LpZWgo

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

//create te container that will hold the boincing balls.
var container = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 600,
    height: 300
};
//create the array of circles that will be animated
var circles = [{
    x: 50,
    y: 100,
    r: 10,
    vx: 10,
    vy: 9,
    color: 125
}, {
    x: 150,
    y: 80,
    r: 20,
    vx: 15,
    vy: 8,
    color: 205
}, {
    x: 90,
    y: 150,
    r: 5,
    vx: 5,
    vy: 15,
    color: 25
}, {
    x: 100,
    y: 50,
    r: 15,
    vx: 8,
    vy: 10,
    color: 100
}];

function animate() {
    //draw the container
    c.fillStyle = "#000000";
    c.fillRect(container.x, container.y, container.width, container.height);

    //loop throughj the circles array
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        //draw the circles
        c.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + circles[i].color++ + ', 100%, 50%)';
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        c.fill()

        //time to animate our circles ladies and gentlemen.
        if (circles[i].x - circles[i].r + circles[i].vx < container.x || circles[i].x + circles[i].r + circles[i].vx > container.x + container.width) {
            circles[i].vx = -circles[i].vx;
        }

        if (circles[i].y + circles[i].r + circles[i].vy > container.y + container.height || circles[i].y - circles[i].r + circles[i].vy < container.y) {
            circles[i].vy = -circles[i].vy;
        }

        circles[i].x += circles[i].vx
        circles[i].y += circles[i].vy
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad in my opinion.

Comment: You will need to add a comparison in loop between current circle (i) with all the others (circles array) so that if they collide they'll bounce between them.

Answer (score 0):

For each square with other squares or each circle with other circles, you can use [a basic collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection):

```
if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
   rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
   rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y) {
    // collision detected!
}

var dx = circle1.x - circle2.x;
var dy = circle1.y - circle2.y;
var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

if (distance < circle1.radius + circle2.radius) {
    // collision detected!
}
```

And then change the way that the speed and direction is attributed.

For collision detection between square and circles, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089959/detecting-collision-of-rectangle-with-circle).

Be carefull to **compare same step's position** in order to avoid comparing an updated value to an old one. For instance you may use a *deep* copy of circles.

```
prevCircles = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(circles));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, how would this work with the circles colliding with the squares that I want to add?

Comment: You may find answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089959/detecting-collision-of-rectangle-with-circle)