# how to detect collisions in JS canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a simple platformer game on the browser using JS canvas and am currently trying to detect collisions between the `Player` class and the `Platform` class. I have done collisions but for different game styles. This is a first for me in JS.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const dimensions = canvas.getBoundingClientRect()
canvas.width = dimensions.width * devicePixelRatio
canvas.height = dimensions.height * devicePixelRatio
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')


canvas.height = (innerHeight / 12) * 11
canvas.width = (innerWidth / 10) * 9

const centerx = canvas.width / 2
const centery = canvas.height / 2

const width = canvas.width
const height = canvas.height


player_acc = 0.5
gravity = 0.01
fricktion = -0.12
class Player {
    constructor(x, y, radius, color, speedX, speedY) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.radius = radius
        this.color = color
        this.speedX = speedX
        this.speedY = speedY
        this.accY = 0
        this.accX = 0
    }

    draw() {
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
        c.fillStyle = this.color
        c.fill()
    }

    update() {
        this.accX = 0
        this.accY = 0.5

        // apply fricktion
        this.accX += this.speedX * fricktion

        // equations of motion
        this.speedX += this.accX
        this.speedY += this.accY

        this.x += this.speedX + 0.5 * this.accX
        this.y += this.speedY + 0.5 * this.accY


    }

}

class Platform {
    constructor(x, y, width, height, color) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.width = width
        this.height = height
        this.color = color
    }

    draw() {
        c.beginPath()
        this.rect = c.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)
        c.fillStyle = this.color
        c.fill()
    }
}


// create things
let player = new Player(
    (width / 12), // X
    (canvas.height / 10) * 7, // Y
    10, // radius
    '#205FE6', // color
    0, // vertical speed
    0, // horizontal speed
    ) 

// create entity lists

// list of all platforms
let platforms = [
    [0, (height / 10) * 8, 200, 50, '#0E2A66']
]

let plats = []


let animationId
function animate() {
    animationId = requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    c.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    player.update()
    player.draw()

    // get the list of platforms created above
    platforms.forEach((plat, index) => {
        plats.push(new Platform(plat[0], plat[1], plat[2], plat[3], plat[4]))
    })

    // draw each platform accordingly
    plats.forEach((p) => {
        p.draw()

        // check for collision between player and platform
        // how do I do this <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


    })

}




// start animate loop
animate()
```

```css
.gameWindow {
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: #6790EA;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="gameWindow"></canvas>
```

Currently the player falls through the platform, which is expected, but what I need it to do is make the players circle's bottom be on the top of the platform

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089959/detecting-collision-of-rectangle-with-circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation on how you can achieve this. First You must remove this

```
platforms.forEach((plat, index) => {
        plats.push(new Platform(plat[0], plat[1], plat[2], plat[3], plat[4]))
    })
```

from your animate loop. Unless your intention is to push another platform into the plats array every frame call then you don't want that. It's bogging down the performance. Just add `console.log(plats.length)` in your loop and see how large it gets.

This should only be called once outside of the loop to create the platforms.

As for the collision you can use something like this as long as the box is axis aligned.

```
function intersection(min, max, value) {
  return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, value));
}
```

I added an `intersectPt` param to your platforms class to track each ones intersection point with the player. Just image a vector from the center of the player to the platform. We need to know that point that the vector would intersect.

```
update() {
    this.intersectPt = { x: intersection(this.x, this.x + this.width, player.x),
                         y: intersection(this.y, this.y + this.width, player.x)};
  }
```

As you can see we will pass in those parameters to the intersection function, mentioned above, to calculate the x and y values of where the vector from the center of the player to the platform happens. Once we know where the intersection point is we can then just determine if the distance from the intersection point is less than the radius;

```
function distance(x, y) {
  return Math.hypot(x, y);
}
```

JS has a bult-in Math.hypot for this. You can also just use any Pythagorean theorem equation written how you prefer.

If it returns true that the distance is less then we can call our response function to do something

```
function collisionResponse(plat) {
  plat.color = "red";
  player.y = plat.y - player.radius;
  player.speedY = 0;
}
```

Here a snippet

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const dimensions = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.width = dimensions.width * devicePixelRatio;
canvas.height = dimensions.height * devicePixelRatio;
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.height = (innerHeight / 12) * 11;
canvas.width = (innerWidth / 10) * 9;

const centerx = canvas.width / 2;
const centery = canvas.height / 2;

const width = canvas.width;
const height = canvas.height;

let player_acc = 0.5;
let gravity = 0.01;
let fricktion = -0.12;
let playerToPlat;

class Player {
  constructor(x, y, radius, color, speedX, speedY) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY = speedY;
    this.accY = 0;
    this.accX = 0;
  }

  draw() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.fillStyle = this.color;
    c.fill();
  }

  update() {
    this.accX = 0;
    this.accY = 0.5;

    // apply fricktion
    this.accX += this.speedX * fricktion;

    // equations of motion
    this.speedX += this.accX;
    this.speedY += this.accY;

    this.x += this.speedX + 0.5 * this.accX;
    this.y += this.speedY + 0.5 * this.accY;
  }
}

class Platform {
  constructor(x, y, width, height, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.color = color;
    this.intersectPt = { x: this.x, y: this.y };
  }

  draw() {
    c.beginPath();
    this.rect = c.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    c.fillStyle = this.color;
    c.fill();
  }
  update() {
    this.intersectPt = {
      x: intersection(this.x, this.x + this.width, player.x),
      y: intersection(this.y, this.y + this.width, player.x)
    };
  }
}

// create things
let player = new Player(
  width / 12, // X
  10, // Y
  10, // radius
  "#205FE6", // color
  0, // vertical speed
  0 // horizontal speed
);

// create entity lists

// list of all platforms
let platforms = [[0, 75, 200, 50, "#0E2A66"]];

let plats = [];

// get the list of platforms created above
platforms.forEach((plat, index) => {
  plats.push(new Platform(plat[0], plat[1], plat[2], plat[3], plat[4]));
});

function intersection(min, max, value) {
  return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, value));
}

function distance(x, y) {
  return Math.hypot(x, y);
}

function collisionResponse(plat) {
  plat.color = "red";
  player.y = plat.y - player.radius;
  player.speedY = 0;
}

let animationId;
function animate() {
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  player.update();
  player.draw();

  // draw each platform accordingly
  plats.forEach((p) => {
    p.draw();
    p.update();
    playerToPlat = distance(
      p.intersectPt.x - player.x,
      p.intersectPt.y - player.y
    );
    if (playerToPlat < player.radius) {
      collisionResponse(p);
    }
  });
}

// start animate loop
animate();
```

```css
.gameWindow {
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: #6790EA;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameWindow"></canvas>
```

Note that I did change the y value of the player and platform to have it visible in the Stackoverflow preview window.

Also always assign a variable the proper way using let, var, or const.